# Application Insights for Azure Functions V.2 not auto-detecting SQL call

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights

I am Attempting to use Application Insights for Azure Functions V.2 to automatically monitor Azure Cosmos DB dependency calls through an SQL API (DocumentClient).

Function accesses Cosmos DB through the SQL API method

*DocumentClient.readDocuments(String collectionLink, FeedOptions options)*

Invocation of the method occurs in a separate package, but is imported with the pom.xml file through maven.

## What's been tried so far

Following documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#dependencies...

-com.microsoft.azure.applicationinsights-core V.2.3.0 added to the pom.xml file

-APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY added to environment variables

-Application Insights Enabled through the Azure Portal and verified as V.2

-Disabled built-in logging by removing AzureWebJobsDashboard Environment 
Variable

-ApplicationInsights.xml added to the classpath and pointed to by JavaOpts

-AI-Agent.xml and applicationinsights-agent-2.3.1.jar were also added to the 
classpath and pointed to by JavaOpts.

-Added Logging Section to Host.JSON to log only trace files

## Desired Behavior

Desired behavior is that the CosmosDB SQL call in CosmosDbConnection.java would result in an automatic dependency trace by Azure Functions V.2

The function itself does appear as a component in the Application Map, but without any logs indicating DB access.

Due to the complexity and number of functions, manually tracking dependencies is not preferable and Any help or suggestions with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: fwiw, this is probably better a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host). This is probably a missing feature rather than a mistake on your part.